# Find a file with path as regular expression

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep, find

I need to find a file named "MyErrors.log" in a directory structure like this :
*

```
./node33/var/log/192.168.176.33-image/MyErrors.log
./node34/var/log/192.168.176.34-image/MyErrors.log
./node35/var/log/192.168.176.35-image/MyErrors.log
./node36/var/log/192.168.176.36-image/MyErrors.log
```

- 

Then need to grep some text in each of them? how can i do that:
I am trying following command to find the file: `find . -name "node*/var/log/*-image/MyErrors.log"` Can anyone help me with the shell script one liner if possible?

Comment: @pLumo Iused find . -path "node*/var/log/*-image/MyErrors.log" . Its not working

Comment: not sure, you may need `./` in the beginning of your path.

Comment: That works! Thanks! @pLumo

Comment: @user1731553, when you post questions asking for help from unpaid strangers, you may want to make sure to explain what, exactly is the part where you have a problem. Right now, your question doesn't say if the issue is with running `grep` on the files, or just finding them (or both). You also probably don't need a regex here, remember that they're different from shell-style pattern matches, which `find -name` and `find -path` use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find -path` with `-exec`:

```
find . -path "./node*/var/log/*-image/MyErrors.log" -exec grep "pattern" {} +
```

Depending on what/how you want to use `grep`, you might need `\;` instead of `+`.

Comment: You may want to add an extra empty file (typically `/dev/null`) to the list of file names passed to `grep` to make sure `grep` always prints the filename even when passed a single file. Or with GNU `grep`, you can use the `-H` option for that.

Comment: May be worth also noting that the `*` can span more than one directory component (could match on `./node1/sub/dir/var/log/old/foo-image/MyErrors.log` for instance). Using `-maxdepth` if supported could work around that.